# How the kernel knows how much headroom/tailroom to assign, when it required to create SKB to send through net-device interface?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, network-programming, driver, linux-device-driver

I have a scenario in which the kernel builds SKB which came to my `.do_start_xmit` hook, without enough headroom for my extra headers.
Actually, it happens when the previous `.do_start_xmit` hook call, returned with an error (not `0`). From that moment, the kernel keep trying to send SKBs (32-words length of data) without enough headroom for my extra headers. Until that error, the kernel made perfect SKBs with enough headroom for everything I needed.

Where is the configuration in which from it the kernel takes the values to set the size of headroom/tailroom of SKB, when sending a ping (for example) from one userspace to another?

Comment: I've done some research, and the thing was that once a SKB couldn't been sent, the kernel kept sending the same SKB even though I pushed some headers into it. Eventually, no more room has left inside this SKB's headroom (the MAX is 'dev->needed_headroom').
Does anyone knows how do I configure a net_device for it's MAX retries per SKB?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set your "net_device" "needed_headroom" / "needed_tailroom" field, at your NIC driver init time, like

dev->needed_headroom += EXTRA_HEADER_LENGTH;

The basic logic is, when networking stack is about to allocate a SKB to transmit via a interface, it take into consideration the value of "needed_headroom" ( in fact, a macro LL_RESERVED_SPACE (dev ) ),  and the SKB would have that large headroom reserved.    This way, your NIC driver could assume that most packet reach into "do_start_xmit()" should have enough headroom --- *most*, not all,  a headroom check is still needed.